# Pre-processing: How to discard GNU extensions?

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to discard GNU extensions while pre-processing a C file?
E.g.: `__attribute__ ((foo))`

Best idea I got for now is to post-process it using regexp, but seems tricky to cover every syntaxes ;{ and not really perennial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't know, but GNU extensions could be properly disabled by setting __GNUC__ to 0, so a simple :
`-D__GNUC__=0` do the trick

Comment: +1 because it worked for me, but be careful; There's a lot of places where the library only checks for `__GNUC__` to be defined but cannot be bothered to check its value (indicating the gcc major version number).

Answer (score 0):

Why not preprocess with `-D__attribute__(x)=` (empty)?

Comment: Sorry, forget backcote around the `__attribute__ ((foo))`, so the __ disappear and bold the text ... My bad